# Ubuntu on HP ProBook 430?

Tags: hp

I am planning to get HP ProBook 430 with 128GB SSD + 500GB HDD, 16GB DDR3, Intel Core i5-5200U. I am not 100% sure if this is a good laptop for a Ubuntu installation? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[This list](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) is the official certified laptops out in the market, (mine is not in the list using it for 2 years now w/out problems). You should check it online by the hardware looking is there any issue..

Edit :Quick research, knowing this pc comes with integrated gpu's it would be flawless in at the motherboard side